# how to disable jQuery.Mobile.MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I building a mobile views for my website and i am still in process of creating them. i want to test how it would look on live device. so i would like to disable the .mobile files and below i tired running some scripts to disable but no luck.

```
<script>$(function () {
$('html').find('*').attr('data-role', 'none');
});
</script>

<script>$(document).ready(function () {
// disable ajax nav
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
</script>
```

Maybe these is a question for the developers but if any one can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable *auto-initialization* `$.mobile.autoInitializePage` of jQuery Mobile framework once `mobileinit` event is fired. Add the below code after jQuery (core) library and before jQuery Mobile in head.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).on('mobileinit', function () {
     $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
  });
</script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></srcipt>
```

To manually *initialize* jQuery Mobile, you need to call `$.mobile.initializePage();`

Comment: Hey thanx for reply, i am not sure where do i add that script in the layout.mobile page or some where else?

Comment: @cooler try layout.mobile where you have markup of JQM pages.

Comment: hey i have tryed that but no luck its still loading the .Mobile files.

Comment: @cooler i'll look for other solutions, there should be a way of communication between both frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

hey Omar thanx for the help but i found it how disable it [blog.mirajavora.com/overriding-browser-capabilities-in-asp.net]

```
public class BrowserCapabilitiesSwitcherFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var switchParameter =         f   filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["switch"];
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(switchParameter))
        return;

    var browserOverride = BrowserOverride.Desktop;
    if(Enum.TryParse(switchParameter, true, out browserOverride))
    {
        //switch between BrowserOverride.Desktop / BrowserOverride.Mobile
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.SetOverriddenBrowser(browserOverride);
    }
    else
    {
        //set the user-agent string
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.SetOverriddenBrowser(switchParameter);
    }            
}
 }
```