# Jquery mobile input override

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Initially I did not know that jquery mobile reformats inputs, but I found out that `.ui-input-text` is the default for jquery mobile. I then wrapped my inputs in their own div with `.panel-input`. I was able to override the default `display:block` with `inline-block` and changed the width. However, for some reason, I cannot figure out how to override the margin.

I am attempting to add margin between the inputs. Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

By the way, I am not using jquery mobile's css file.

```css
.proposal-input, .proposal-text {
 border: 1px solid #858585;
 background: #333333;
 font-size: 1.4rem;
 padding: 15px 8px;
 color: #858585;
 outline: none;
 font-family: Helvetica;
 margin: 1.5% 2% 2.5% 2%; !important
}
.panel-input {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 44%; !important
 margin: 1.5% 2% 2.5% 2%; !important
}
.ui-input-text, .proposal-input {
 width: 100%;
}
.proposal-text {
 width: 94%;
 display: block;
 height: 6em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-input"><input type="text" class="proposal-input" placeholder="Name *"></div>
<div class="panel-input"><input type="text" class="proposal-input" placeholder="Email *"></div>
<div class="panel-input"><input type="text" class="proposal-input" placeholder="Phone *"></div>
<div class="panel-input"><input type="text" class="proposal-input" placeholder="Location *"></div>
```

Comment: Are you referring to the left,right margin? It looks like top and bottom work fine.

Comment: @tonyM I am trying to get margin in between the inputs.

Comment: Add `data-wrapper-class` attribute to input and then do changes you want in that class. E.g. `<input type="text" data-wrapper-class="custom"/>` `.custom { /* whatever you want */ }`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15678288/1771795

Comment: @Omar No luck. Thanks though.

Comment: I just noticed that you aren't using jQM CSS, what's the purpose of using jQM framework without its' CSS?

Comment: Id go for this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/21185237/1771795 to avoid extra markup.

Comment: @Omar So, I have to add `data-enhance="false"` to every div on my entire page? I am not using JQM's css because I don't need it. I am just using the framework to be able to use the `swipeRight` function.

Comment: @Paul you can create your swipe events without using jQM. I really don't recommend using it just to use some features. To answer your question, if you insist on using jQM then you need to stop jQM from doing anything, but still can take adventage of swipe events. Follow this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/25188162/1771795) you don't even need to initialize it manually, just prevent it from auto-init. Good luck.

Comment: @Omar Thank you for the help. How can I do a swipe event without jquery mobile?

Comment: https://hammerjs.github.io/ better to use a dedicated touch library, or create your own events by listening to touch events.

Comment: @Omar Thank you! That works so much better! What is the point of using jquery mobile? Feel free to leave an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `box-sizing` for the input. You may have to decrease `width` for the div in order for changes to be noticeable. Something like this:

`box-sizing: border-box;` 
for this selector:
`.proposal-input, .proposal-text`

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kby203Ln/1/

Edit:

This is what changed:

```css
.proposal-input, .proposal-text {
 border: 1px solid #858585;
 background: #333333;
 font-size: 1.4rem;
 padding: 15px 8px;
 color: #858585;
 outline: none;
 font-family: Helvetica;
 margin: 1.5% 2% 2.5% 2%; !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;/* added this*/
}

.panel-input {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 40%; !important; /* changed width from 44 to 40 */
 margin: 1.5% 2% 2.5% 2%; !important;
}
```

Comment: I don't see what you changed, but the result is there?

Comment: Actually that fiddle didn't save properly. Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/kby203Ln/1/ . I added `box-sizing: border-box;` to the selector `.proposal-input, .proposal-text` and decreased the div width `.panel-input` to `40%`

Comment: I added those elements, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Is this the result you're looking for? https://ibb.co/enPro5 Perhaps I misunderstood your intent.

Comment: Your jsfiddle is what I am looking for, but it is not rendering the results on my page.

Comment: Is this on mobile?

Comment: On line 514 of index2. Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.proposal-input, .proposal-text`. Doing so on devtools adds the margin (rather, displays it).

Comment: I had `box-sizing: border-box` in that block of css though? I just raised it to where you said and I am still not seeing the change?

Comment: It now shows up, could have been a cache. Looks good though. Please accept the answer once you confirm solution. This is what shows up (in case you're still cached):  https://ibb.co/iYMqFk

Comment: This still doesn't affect the margin though? The left and right margin does not work.

Comment: Oh I see. Add margin to the div. So for instance `margin: 0 3%;` and decrease with to `30%` on .panel-input. https://ibb.co/i5RJ1Q

Comment: I know how to set margins and width. The issue is the margin setting are not working. I just switched the right margin from 2% to 30% and nothing changed.

Comment: I meant margin on the div `.panel-input`

Comment: I have that. I just don't get why it isn't working. I have never had this happen before. `.panel-input {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 40%; !important
 margin: 1.5% 2% 2.5% 2%; !important
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142854/discussion-between-tony-m-and-paul).